# Show hidden divs one at a time

Tags: javascript, html

I have 4 hidden divs that I need to show one at a time.

With the code I have, when I click on one of the buttons, it shows the content of the corresponding hidden div and if I click on the same button it will hide the content; however, if I click once on more than one button, it will show the contents corresponding to every button I clicked.

What I need is that if I click on one button to show one div, when I click on another, the previous one goes away and the new one shows.

I am very new at this and will appreciate if someone can help me out. I did try many of the solutions to related questions but unable to get it to work correctly

```
<p class="btn " onclick="$('#div1').toggle(800);">Show div1</p>
<p class="btn " onclick="$('#div2').toggle(800);">Show div2</p>
<p class="btn " onclick="$('#div3').toggle(800);">Show div3</p>
<p class="btn " onclick="$('#div4').toggle(800);">Show div4</p>

<div id="div1" style="display:none"; >
 <div class="container">
    <p>This is the content of div1</p>
 </div>
</div>

<div id="div2" style="display:none"; >
 <div class="container">
    <p>This is the content of div2</p>
 </div>
</div>

<div id="div3" style="display:none"; >
 <div class="container">
    <p>This is the content of div3</p>
 </div>
</div>

<div id="div4" style="display:none"; >
 <div class="container">
    <p>This is the content of div4</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just `.toggle()` other divs in the callback function

Comment: I couldn't get it "click once on more than one button" - you literally can't click 2 buttons at the same time. Please explain in better language?

Comment: You described example of [Accordion control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accordion_%28GUI%29)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to do is tie your buttons, and the divs they act on together in a more semantic way, perhaps using `data-` attributes:

```
<p class="btn " data-linkedto="#div1">Show div1</p>
<p class="btn " data-linkedto="#div2">Show div2</p>
<p class="btn " data-linkedto="#div3">Show div3</p>
<p class="btn " data-linkedto="#div4">Show div4</p>
```

Then, when you click on any given button, you can hide all divs, and only show the one that is linked:

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
   // get the div to show
   var linkedDiv = $(this).data('linkedto')
   // hide all the divs
   $('div.container').parent('div').hide();
   // show the linked one
   $(linkedDiv).show();
});
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/negk7937/

The middle line there:

```
$('div.container').parent('div').hide();
```

Is a little over-complicated by not having a class on the wrapper around each `.container` - this can be solved by adding it:

```
<div id="div1" class="container-wrapper" style="display:none"; >
 <div class="container">
    <p>This is the content of div1</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

And then the middle line becomes, simply:

```
$('div.container-wrapper').hide();
```

Comment: This is by far the most correct answer and it's BARELY complicated using jquery.

Answer (score 2):

First, we can make a single function call for all of these:

Also I would suggest giving all the tags you want to fade out a unique CLASS

```
<p class="btn" onclick="toggleDivs('#div1');">Show div1</p>

<div class="fadeOut" id="div1" style="display:none"; >
    <div class="container">
        <p>This is the content of div1</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Next, the function:

This checks if the div that has been selected is hidden, and if it is the function runs. If it is visible it is the currently selected div and nothing happens.

```
var toggleDivs = function (id) {
    if ($(id).css('display') === 'none') {
        $(".fadeOut").hide(800);
        $(id).show(800);
    }
}
```

Hope it works!

Comment: I think this has it the wrong way round, this is showing the associated div, but fading out the buttons

Comment: It works great. Thank you very, very much. And thanks to the other members for so many solutions. I really appreciate it.

Comment: The above solution worked almost perfect.
 
If I click on a button it will show the div and when I click on another it will hide the previous div and show the next one.

The only issue I had was that that if I clicked to show a div and clicked on the same button to hide it, it was going away and showing up right back.

I solved that issue by changing $ (id) .show (800) to $ (id) .show ().

But now I do not have any “In” effect when I click on any of the buttons to show a div.

Is there any way you or someone can help me to add that effect?

Comment: @Palca I added a css check in the `toggleDivs` function, see if that works for you. (Sorry for the delay, was on my weekend)

Answer (score 1):

Check out the below code

```js
$('p').on('click', function(){
   var target = $(this).attr('rel');
   $("#"+target).show().siblings("div").hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="btn" rel="div1">Show div1</p>
<p class="btn" rel="div2">Show div2</p>
<p class="btn" rel="div3">Show div3</p>
<p class="btn" rel="div4">Show div4</p>

<div id="div1" style="display:none"; >
 <div class="container">
    <p>This is the content of div1</p>
 </div>
</div>

<div id="div2" style="display:none"; >
 <div class="container">
    <p>This is the content of div2</p>
 </div>
</div>

<div id="div3" style="display:none"; >
 <div class="container">
    <p>This is the content of div3</p>
 </div>
</div>

<div id="div4" style="display:none"; >
 <div class="container">
    <p>This is the content of div4</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

This is the simplest way to do it. Just create a function and execute a list of operations there. You can also keep using toggle instead of hide and show.

```
 <script>
    function expandDiv(div){
       $('#div1').hide();
       $('#div2').hide();
       $('#div3').hide();
       $('#div4').hide();
       $('#'+div).show();
    }
    </script>

    <p class="btn " onclick="expandDiv('div1');">Show div1</p>
    <p class="btn " onclick="expandDiv('div2');">Show div2</p>
    <p class="btn " onclick="expandDiv('div3');">Show div3</p>
    <p class="btn " onclick="expandDiv('div4');">Show div4</p>
```

Comment: My downvote here is because this is not a scalable solution. Every new div requires going back and adding another line into `expandDiv`

Answer (score -1):

Something quick:

```
<p class="btn" id="p1" onclick="$('.cont').hide();$('#div1').toggle(800);">Show div1</p>
<p class="btn" id="p2" onclick="$('.cont').hide();$('#div2').toggle(800);">Show div2</p>
<p class="btn" id="p3" onclick="$('.cont').hide();$('#div3').toggle(800);">Show div3</p>
<p class="btn" id="p4" onclick="$('.cont').hide();$('#div4').toggle(800);">Show div4</p>

<div class="cont" id="div1" style="display:none"; >
 <div class="container">
    <p>This is the content of div1</p>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="cont" id="div2" style="display:none"; >
 <div class="container">
    <p>This is the content of div2</p>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="cont" id="div3" style="display:none"; >
 <div class="container">
    <p>This is the content of div3</p>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="cont" id="div4" style="display:none"; >
 <div class="container">
    <p>This is the content of div4</p>
 </div>
</div>
```